# How can I change font style for part of a text in android webView

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to add different String elements with different font styles to one webView in android. I have done the same thing using textView before, but I don't know how to do it with webView

Comment: In  aTextView you could possibly have used `Html.fromHTML()`. Then, you already know how HTML works, don't you?

Comment: In textView I have such code:

   Spannable text = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(childBody.get(1).toString()));
Then I add it to my textView

Comment: What's the content of `childBody.get(1).toString()`?

Comment: childBody.get(1) is html type, and I am converting it to String using toString()

Comment: HTML is **always** a string. I'd like to know WHAT is this string. I.e: `"<font color='red'>Some text</font>"`.

Comment: It's a long html text extracted from a website, and saved in a MySQL database. Now I am reading it from database, and I want to format different parts like title, footnote, etc. as I want.

Comment: Just put the same html into the webview

Comment: Here is part of the html if you want to see:

<p> <em>Enables CPSO registration for academic practice for eligible applicants who do not meet the regulatory requirements (e.g. certification by examination by the Royal College of Physicians and Surgeons of Canada or the College of Family Physicians of Canada) for a regular Academic Practice Certificate. </em></p> 
<h2 class="table-of-contents"> Purpose</h2>

Comment: Since WebViews are explicitly done for parsing HTML (while TextViews are **not**)... I don't see which is the problem

Comment: Let's guess the html text is originally green, and I want part of it black, and another part blue. I want to get full control over it's style

Comment: Use a CSS and you're good to go.

Comment: I didn't think about CSS. I will try it. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. I use HTML files from my asset folders for providing a user guide, And I use CSS to conform the HTML to my app style.